# How to use cordova-plugin-qrscanner inside Angular 4 project

Tags: angular, cordova, cross-platform

I'm developing angular 4 application.It directly converts to Cordova by using a hook.In that Angular application, I want to use [cordova-plugin-qrscanner](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner) plugin.

I have tried like billows but it is not working

inside type script

```
declare var QRScanner: any; declare the veriable
```

then it use inside a method

```
scan() {
var done = function(err, status){
  if(err){
    console.error(err._message);
  } else {
    console.log('QRScanner is initialized. Status:');
    console.log(status);
  }
};

QRScanner.prepare(done);
QRScanner.show();

var callback = function(err, contents){
  if(err){
    console.error(err._message);
  }
  alert('The QR Code contains: ' + contents);
};

QRScanner.scan(callback);
```

}

call in the click function

```
<button type="submit" (click)="scan()"> Scan </button>
```

But not working.Also not coming any error

Comment: You probably need camera permission before you can use this plugin.

Comment: i have already added camera permission in the config.xml.But not working

Comment: If your device is running Android 6.0 or higher you need to request the permission at runtime - the user has to confirm it.

Comment: I use `QRScanner.prepare(done);` as an above-mentioned code to get permission in the phone.But it did not prompt anything to ask permission.

Comment: Is there a sample project for that plugin.I can't figure out what is the error.because it do not prompt any errors in console.

Comment: Did you set the background of all of your html elements to transparent? The docs mention that the camera preview is launched _behind_ the webview, so everything on it has to be transparent to actually see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `( < any > window).QRScanner`  to get access to the QRScanner plugin.

It will be available after  `deviceready`  event is handled

Comment: Good day @Shailesh, may I know how can I know the `deviceready` event is handled? I tried this way, but hitting unexpected error, error message is "QRScanner returned an invalid error code.". Could you help me on this?